# How to use JSPM to convert an Angular2 app into a single .js file?

Tags: angular, jspm

What are the simple steps that can convert an Angular2 app into a single (or a few) `.js` files?

The Angular2 app already runs on the local machine, but it uses the `node_modules` folder which is close to 200MB.  It is said that JSPM can pack the needed `.js` files into 1 single file -- how is it done?

Comment: [straight from the mouth of one of the masters](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/429e01c6d802767441ec)

Comment: seems quite complicated... there isn't a couple of command lines that can do the work?  programming seems like becoming configuration work

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html). For example, if you have a systemjs config like this:

```
  <!doctype html>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app/main.js');
    </script>
```

you can bundle like this

```
jspm bundle app/main main-bundle.js --inject
```

or, even better, like this (to create an output distributable script file that can be included entirely on its own independent):

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/main.js app.js
```

> app.js contains a micro-loader implementation (1.4KB gzipped),
>   converts all module formats into ES5 (including compiling ES6), and
>   maintaining bindings and circular references as with normal bundles

To use JSPM you need to use SystemJS and the config.js file. If you think the [link](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/429e01c6d802767441ec) suggested by @drewmoore is too complicated maybe you're not approaching the problem correctly.